# Reload page, keep sessions

Tags: php, session, post, refresh

I'm trying to develop a function where a user can click "Previos week"/"Next week" and that will trigger some `$_SESSION` variables to change values (dates).

I have this code on **absence.php** (I know that PRG pattern is not implemented. I have no idea on how to do this but still keep functionality).

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['decrease_date'])) {
    $monday_value = ($_SESSION['sess_mon'] = strftime("%Y-%m-%d", strtotime("{$_SESSION['sess_mon']} -1 day")) );
}
if (isset($_POST['increase_date'])) {
    $monday_value = ($_SESSION['sess_mon'] = strftime("%Y-%m-%d", strtotime("{$_SESSION['sess_mon']} +1 day")) );
}
else {
    $monday_value = ($_SESSION['sess_mon'] = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('Monday this week')) );
}
?>

 <form action='absence.php' method='post'>
  <input type="hidden" name="decrease_date"/>
  <input type='submit' value='Previous'>
 </form>

<form action='absence.php' method='post'>
 <input type="hidden" name="increase_date"/>
<input type='submit' value='Next'>
</form>
```

Now I would like to reload the page (with jQuery `location.reload()`-function) but still keep the `$_SESSION`s what was active at the moment before the page was refreshed. Currently this will "reset" since there is no `$_POST`.

Ideally I would like to send the `<form action'#'>` to another page. However when you first enter **absence.php** the dates should be reset.

How would I do this?

Answer (score 1):

change

```
session_start();
```

into:

```
if (!isset($_SESSION)){
  session_start();
}
```

Comment: I'm curious. How would this help me?

Comment: you do not create a new session every time you post the form

Comment: Oh, I forgot that I don't need the session_start() at all since it's inherited from another page. **absence.php** is included inside **index.php**

Comment: sorry, I didn't fully get your question too, actually my answer is only a comment... :D

Answer (score 0):

Instead of reloading, can't you just submit form by jquery `$("form#frmDate").submit();` Don't forget to give ID to your form `frmDate`.

Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: I don't think it's what I'm looking for. The variables is used inside a MySQL query to list rows, with colors changing based on values, like a data-grid. And whenever a user has edit a row and click "Save" I want the data to be reloaded.